# time evolution with Matlab BVP4C

Tags: differential-equations

is there any way to simulate the time evolution of a BVP with bvp4c? I have a problem with a moving boundary and I created a cycle over the position in time of the moving boundary. At each iteration, the bvp4c Matlab solver calculates the solution by taking as initial guess, the solution from the previous one, knowing the current position of the boundary in object. This is my trick to include time in your system of equations. But, as I am including the time evolution of temperature, I am doubting this is the right approach. I cannot use PDEs for this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: So the situation is that x'=f(t,x,q) with boundary conditions on x(0) and x(L(q)), where L(q) is also not directly known, and you want to compute solutions for changing parameter q? This would match your strategy, but it seems your problem is more complicated?

Comment: the situation is exactly the way you described. Though, together with the equations that describe the mechanics, there is one for temperature. and this one should affect my mechanical properties over time.

Comment: Your approach looks correct. You could include some extrapolation of the state vs. the temperature if you want to use a larger time step resp. get a better initial estimate for faster convergence.

Comment: thank you for your reply. However, what do you mean with state?

Comment: State space is where the solution curve lives in, but in this instance I should have better written solution curve, as that is the object that gets extrapolated. Using the same value as you did is extrapolation by a constant function, I meant using linear or quadratic extrapolation.